# Console app state changed event/callback - how it can be done (notified when it starts waiting for input)?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, windows, winapi

How can I get notification when a ***console process*** thread's state is changed?

Again - this is a console window process (`cmd.exe`) - I need to interact with it based on whether it's expecting an input, and I have several of those, and I listen to several events (such as `stdout` string is emitted)

I can utilize `ProcessThread.ThreadState` and `ProcessThread.WaitReason` to query current state, but I need event driven pattern.

Is it possible maybe via Windows Hooks, or some other mechanism?

## Edit:

I opened [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29790887/console-app-state-changed-event-callback-how-it-can-be-done-notified-when-it) since I wholly missed with this question... don't know whether to close this one or not...

Comment: why is this tagged `c++`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pattern to handle threads status in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483056/pattern-to-handle-threads-status-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I'm curious: Why do you need this? What are you planning to do with that?

Comment: @SelçukCihan That's no way related to this question.

Comment: @m.s. - because I'm pretty sure it would require either P/Invoke or low-level win-hook DLL

Comment: @SelçukCihan - sorry for not being precise. I edited the question regarding the nature of the target process/thread

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - I have to interact with console app via `stdin`

Answer (score 0):

Use an EventWaitHandle to allow a thread to signal that a specific event has occurred to a waiting thread - see [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27366/Beginner-s-Guide-to-Threading-in-NET-Part-of-n) link for an example. You don't provide any further details in your question but this should get you started.

Comment: Sorry for not being precise. I edited the question regarding the nature of the target process/thread - it's a console app whose code is not available to me

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't need to be as low level as ThreadState you could drive this in your thread handling code and use something like an AutoResetEvent to signal a status change.

Comment: Sorry for not being precise. I edited the question regarding the nature of the target process/thread - it's a console app whose code is not available to me

Answer (score 0):

Can you look at following link:

http://blogs.msmvps.com/luisabreu/blog/2007/09/24/c-signaling-state-changes-through-events/

Might useful for you.

Edit:

From Microsoft :

> To execute a time-consuming operation in the background, create a
>   BackgroundWorker and listen for events that report the progress of
>   your operation and signal when your operation is finished. You can
>   create the BackgroundWorker programmatically or you can drag it onto
>   your form from the Components tab of the Toolbox. If you create the
>   BackgroundWorker in the Windows Forms Designer, it will appear in the
>   Component Tray, and its properties will be displayed in the Properties
>   window.

Have a detail look at class and its member:

[BackgroundWorker Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

This could be a solution which raises an event which you might looking for. Hope this time it helps. :)

Comment: Not related. It's about `delegate`s and `event`s. Nothing regarding threads